# How to create map of scoped_ptr in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, scoped-ptr

I have the following code and line 2 gives me an error during compilation. Is it possible to create a map of scoped pointers or do I have to use shared pointers instead?

```
map<int, scoped_ptr> mp;
mp[1] = scoped_ptr(new obj());
```

error:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<T>& boost::scoped_ptr<T>::operator=(const boost::scoped_ptr<T>&) [with T = ]’ is private
```

Comment: `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` ? C++11 ?

Comment: if you don't have access to c++11, use boost::ptr_container. it does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, `boost::scoped_ptr` is [non-copyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) by design (emphasis mine):

> The scoped_ptr template is a simple solution for simple needs. It supplies a basic "resource acquisition is initialization" facility, without shared-ownership or transfer-of-ownership semantics. Both its name and enforcement of semantics (**by being noncopyable**) signal its intent to retain ownership solely within the current scope.
>
> <...>
>
> **scoped_ptr cannot be used in C++ Standard Library containers. Use shared_ptr if you need a smart pointer that can.**

You can, however, *emplace* `shared_ptr`s into a container, since in this case no copying is performed:

```
std::list<boost::scoped_ptr<MyClass>> list;
list.emplace_back(new MyClass());
```

Comment: does this mean that scoped pointers can't be used with containers?

Comment: @mlmostafa, yes, it's explicitly stated in the documentation that you can't use it in standard library containers

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I think you need to clarify this more. They _can_ be used, you just need to be careful to move/emplace the `scoped_ptr`s, not copy them.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::scoped_ptr` is non-copyable, but you still can swap it.

Here is a trick :

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, boost::scoped_ptr<int>> myMap;

  int * test = new int();
  *test = 589;

  boost::scoped_ptr<int> myScoped(test);

  boost::swap(myMap[1], myScoped);

  std::cout << *myMap[1];

}
```

Gives :

```
589
```

See on C++ Shell : http://cpp.sh/3zm3

However, I advise you not to do it.